# How to display line break <br> between <div> tags in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to get text from a `mysql` database and insert the text into a website. But line breaks are output as text.

```
<div class="span-comment">{{ str_replace('\n', "<br>", mb_substr($message->description, 0, 256)) }}</div>
```

I have already tried many different options, but each time it displays the text `"some text<br>new line"`. Maybe someone faced with such a problem, help.

Comment: Use `{!! !!}}` instead of `{{ }}`; `{{ }}` outputs text literally, including any HTML content, while `{!! !!}` parses HTML: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/blade#displaying-unescaped-data

Comment: Also, you don't need `str_replace()` here; PHP has a `nl2br()` function to convert newlines to `<br/>`: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Answer (score -1):

It seems like you're on the right track with using str_replace to replace newline characters with 
 tags. However, it looks like you're using single quotes for the string that you're passing to str_replace. In PHP, escape sequences such as \n are only interpreted inside double quotes. Therefore, you should change your code to use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```
<div class="span-comment">{{ str_replace("\n", "<br>", mb_substr($message->description, 0, 256)) }}</div>
```

**This should replace newline characters with 
 tags and display them as line breaks in your HTML.

**